# MongoDB: Dotted field is not valid for storage

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to add an object to a array at the **first** position. In this example it is the array `description.en`

So this is my document structure:

```
{
  _id: 'Aw5szXgeujrbhwY2r',
  description: {
    en: [
      {
        content: 'Need to change this',
        timestamp: 1480186254
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to do that:

```
const name = 'description' // need to be dynamic
const language = 'en' // need to be dynamic

update = {
  [name + '.' + language]: {
    $position: 0,
    $each: [{
      content: 'New content',
      timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    }]
  }
}

return Content.update({ _id }, update)
```

But I do get the error `MongoError: The dotted field 'description.en' in 'description.en' is not valid for storage.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use mongo's `$push` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push

```
update = {
  $push: {
    [name + '.' + language]: {
       $position: 0,
       $each: [{
         content: 'New content',
         timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use `$set` with dot notation to specify the element

```
update = {
  $set: {
    [name]: {
       [language + '.0']: {
          content: 'New content',
          timestamp
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn... Missed that. Thank you for your help.